# How to Delete a excel file xlsx from the directory

Tags: java, excel, apache, xlsx, delete-file

I´m trying deleted a excel file , but I don´t know how to delete it.
I saw APache Poi API but i don´t found any method or class for it.

the only one way that I did was it:

```
File f1 = new File("D:\\exceltest1.xlsx");
f1.delete();
```

with this code didn´t work, I think it working only with .txt file.

Can anyone help me with it, please?

Comment: any error? is the file not deleted using your code?

Comment: I don´t get any error or exception, I don´t know Why my code not found the file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some exceptions?
The method delete return TRUE if the file deleted and FALSE if not deleted.
You can use this case:

```
File f1 = new File("D:\\exceltest1.xlsx");
if (f1.delete()) {
    System.out.println("File " + f1.getName() + " is deleted.");
} else {
    System.out.println("File " + f1.getName() + " not found.");
}
```

Comment: I don´t get any error or exception, I don´t know Why my code not found the file.  I tried make a test with .txt file and was right and with xslx file my application no found my file. Why?  With that if  I got it :File exceltest1.xlsx not found.